# How to intercept http/https calls after original WkWebview call?

Tags: ios, angularjs, https, wkwebview, squid

The iOS application we have has a WkWebview that tries to communicate with our server by calling a https endpoint.  The server works similar to a proxy and all calls to our endpoint will then forward the request to the destination site.  For example - in our app if we were to set our destination to https://www.google.com the application will translate that to https://server.com/http://www.google.com.

The problem we are trying to solve is the interception of all http/https calls after the original WkWebview call.  This includes all resource calls like css and javascript files.  We have tried to use a custom scheme handler but since we do not parse the html/css on the server side we cannot add a custom scheme to intercept all http/https calls.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the interception logic inside the webview for example every request store url and current number of calls inside a hidden element , and check it's value periodically by evaluteJavaScript function of the webview for that element